# Remove view from RAM swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using segue navigation with `self.perfomSegueWithIndentifier` function with type of `show` segues.I noticed after every navigation other view/viewcontroller did not remove from RAM.What I have to do to solve this

Comment: Are you saying that your view controller object is retained even after you dismiss view controller? If so, check if there are some retain cycles.

Comment: I think he is pushing view controllers in his navigation stack again and again that is consuming more and more ram. You can `popToRootViewController` on your navigation controller before executing segue.

Comment: yes,exactly.Lets say i have to buttons 1-navigating to second viewcontroller 2-navigating to first view controller,and i want to delete previous viewcontroller after navigation

Comment: @ryancrunchi can you add some code,or link for using `popToRootViewController`

Comment: then when you coming from 2VC to 1VC just do `popToViewController`. you flow is VC1 -> VC2 and then VC2 -> VC 1 right

Comment: Can someone add little code doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Programmatically**

Lets say you have `VC1` embed in `UINavigationController` for now `VC1` becomes the top view controller on the navigation stack.

So if you are going `VC1 -> VC2`

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)`

In that case `VC2` becomes the top view controller on the navigation stack.

and while coming back from `VC2 -> VC1` (Button tap on `VC2` perform this statement)

`self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

In that case again `VC1` becomes the top view controller on the navigation stack.

**Using Segue**

Just use `Show(e.g Push)` and set the identifier for that like i have `pushView`
and invoke

`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pushView", sender: nil)` for moving `VC1 -> VC2`

and for coming back to `VC2 -> VC1`

use the same `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

[image]

Comment: you dont use segues am i right?i dont us `UINavigationController`.I have simple viewControllers with segue navigations

Comment: yes but now i have also added example for that as well.

Comment: And what if I navigate to vc2 and after that vc3,in this case does it remove vc1 from RAM?

Comment: No if you move from `VC2 -> VC3` then your top view will be `VC3` and yes it will not remove `VC1` then your stack will look like `VC1->VC2->VC3(topView)`.

Comment: In this case I want to remove it,it will be perfect if vc1 and vc2 removed when i navigate to vc3,how to  achieve it

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

**On Button Tap on View Controller 1:**

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

**On Button Tap on View Controller 2:**

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: If you are doing segue way, implement `unwind` correctly. Take a look at this [blog](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/).

Comment: Please read my comments to the another answer,can you explain me how to remove view from RAM while navigating